# CodedUI not recognizing HtmlControl when searched within scope of UITestControl instead of BrowserWindow

Tags: c#, inheritance, coded-ui-tests

In our Page Object Model for `Page` we initialize a `Container` in the constructor and we define a `HtmlEdit` called `MyTextBox` and a method that uses this text box to search.

```
public class Page 
{
    private readonly UITestControl _container;
    private HtmlEdit _myTextBox;
    private const string MyTextBoxId = "MyTextBoxHtmlId";

    protected Page()
    { }

    protected Page(Process process)
    {
        CurrentBrowser = BrowserWindow.FromProcess(process);
        _container = CurrentBrowser;
    }

    public UITestControl Container
    {
       get { return _container; }
    }

    protected HtmlEdit MyTextBox
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myTextBox == null)
            {
                _myTextBox = Container.FindHtmlEditById(MyTextBoxId);
            }

            return _myTextBox;
        }
    }

    public Page SearchMethod(string accountId)
    {
         MyTextBox.CopyPastedText = accountId;

         // Do the search

         return this;
    }
}
```

Here we want to use a `UITestControl` as container so that we can search within a specific area of the page. The `FindHtmlEditById` extension method in the getter finds the element by its html id as follows:

```
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static HtmlEdit FindHtmlEditById(this UITestControl control, string id)
    {
        return new HtmlEdit(control).FindById(id);
    }

    public static TUIControl FindById<TUIControl>(this TUIControl control, string id) 
         where TUIControl : HtmlControl 
    {
        control.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, id, 
            PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

        return control;
    }
}
```

So `FindHtmlEditById` searches for an element with a certain id within the scope of the `Container`.

When we execute the code and executions arrives at pasting text into `MyTextBox` we get the following error:

> MyTextBox.CopyPastedText = 'MyTextBox.CopyPastedText' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Furthermore, the `ControlType` of `MyTextBox` is `Window` as can be seen here:

[image: NotSupportedException]

When the type of the `Container` field in the the `Page` is changed to `BrowserWindow` as follows:

```
private readonly BrowserWindow _container;

public BrowserWindow Container
{
    get { return _container; }
}
```

`MyTextBox` is properly recognized as a `HtmlEdit`:

[image: Properly recognized as <code>HtmlEdit</code>]

`BrowserWindow` inherits from `UITestControl`. Why then does the `Container` needs to be specified as a `BrowserWindow` to work? Why does it not work as a `UITestControl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide a zip with a repro so I can have a closer look? It is obvious from the screenshots that in the one case you get a Window control back in stead of the HtmlEdit you are searching for, but as the reason why I can not give a conclusive answer. There might be a bug in your code with the CurrentBrowser since that seems to be a construct that is not correct, but also can be a flaw in the pasted code only. I copied the code and tried to reproduce using the bing homepage as the page to past the text in, and that works like a charm. So I suspect the search results in something different in your target website. One thing that might be causing this is the contains operator you use on the search, since this could potentially result in multiple matches depending on the page you are conducting the search on. When it returns multiple controls your call wil also fail, but looking at the whatch you shoed you did not get multiple controls but a window with a windows class edit, which much more looks like a WinEdit control then a HtmlEdit control.

Comment: Thanks for your offer for help. Regarding the multiple results: should this not also happen on a `BrowserWindow` instead of `TUITestControl` as `Container`? I tried to make a solution to isolate and reproduce the issue, but could not do so. The actual intranet page we test it on consists of IFrames, this might have to do with it. But we actually still have no idea why this happened. Since the workaround is just using the `BrowserWindow` we decided to not spend anymore time on this issue. I don't think you can help us further with more details so let's leave it at this. Thanks for reaching out.

Answer (score 1):

`BrowserWindow` does not inherit from `UITestControl`, but is its own class under `UITesting` [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.aspx).  As such, it will have its own properties, methods, etc. Create your object as a BrowserWindow object to solve your exception.

However, to answer your more general inheritance question, even if `BrowserWindow` inherited from `UITestControl`, when dealing with inheritance: While the child will inherit all properties and methods from the parent, the parent will not have any of the methods that are created or overridden in its children.  Thus, `BrowserWindow` can have a method `.FindMyHtmlById()`, but that wouldn't be available if your object was a `UITestControl` type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think you understood the question correctly, or I am misunderstanding you. `BrowserWindow` does inherit from `UITestControl`. See the [inheritance hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.browserwindow.aspx) on MSDN. Furthermore, the method `FindMyHtmlById` is available. It just returns a different type of TextBox as can be seen in the images above.

Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671337/codedui-object-creation-based-on-uitestcontrol.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about the inheritance.  Sorry, I mis-read the MSDN article I found.  It looks like your main issue is with locating your text box as an HtmlEdit rather than a Window.  I'll write another answer to explain.